# Telerik MVC Grid. How to change grid edit mode on client side?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid

I need custom grid behavior on client side: on press Add button, grid create new row in InLine mode, and on press Add2 button, grid create new row in InForm mode, with additional functionality. I add new custom command in toolbar and call javascript function Add2, where try change grid edit mode. But edit mode not changed, new row created in InLine mode. What I do wrong, and in general, is it possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Add2() {
        var grid = $('#Property').data('tGrid');
        grid.editing.mode = 'InForm';
        grid.addRow();
    }
</script>

Html.Telerik().Grid<Models.PropertyTypeModel>().Name("Property")
            //  skip
            .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
            {
                dataBinding.Ajax()
                    .Select("_PropertySelect", "Options", new { oid = "<#= OptionTypeID #>" })
                    //  skip
            })
            .ToolBar(commands => 
            {
                commands.Insert().ButtonType(GridButtonType.ImageAndText);
                commands.Custom().Text("Add2").Url("javascript:void(0)").HtmlAttributes(new { onclick = "Add2()" });
            })
            .Editable(editing => editing
                .Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)
            )
)
```

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported.